# What does a value with e` mean in windbg

Tags: c++, debugging, windbg, size-t

I was using windbg to analyze a crash dump, for one of the variable of type unsigned long long, in the locals I can see its value being "0x002a002e`002a0000". What does value before and after e mean. Also what e(acute) itself mean?

[image]

Comment: The `e` is a hex digit. The character after it is a grouping character used to make the full 16 hex-digit number easier to read (like a comma or period is for large decimal numbers). Otherwise you'd see `0x002a002e002a0000`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format is described in [MASM numbers and operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/masm-numbers-and-operators). So the `e` is, just like the `a` part of a hexadecimal number. A 64 bit hex number is separated into two 32 bit parts by the accent for readability purposes. Using the accent may have more implications, as defined in the definitions for [sign extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/sign-extension).

With all that said, the value `002a002e002a0000` looks very similar to the UTF16 string `*.*`. So maybe you had a buffer overrun somewhere.

```
0:000> .dvalloc 1000
Allocated 1000 bytes starting at 000001d6`4a4c0000
0:000> eq 000001d6`4a4c0000 002a002e002a0000
0:000> dq 000001d6`4a4c0000 L1
000001d6`4a4c0000  002a002e`002a0000
0:000> du 000001d6`4a4c0000 + 2
000001d6`4a4c0002  "*.*"
```